# How to define the distributional Hessian for a convex function on a $C^0$ Riemannian manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

M is a $C^1$ manifold with a $C^0$ Riemannian metric, f is a convex function on M. How to define a functional on M which can represent $Hessf$?

For example: for $\Delta f$ we can define the corresponding functional:
$$
 Lap f(\phi)=\int_M \langle \nabla f,\nabla\phi \rangle
$$
for Lipschitz function $\phi$ with compact support.

Comment: Any differential operator with smooth coefficients acts on distributions,

Comment: @AlexanderShamov:I add a condition M is $C^0$ Riemannian maniold. And would you please write it in detail?

Comment: My comment would only apply if the manifold and the metric were smooth, in which case $f \mapsto \nabla^2 f$ would be a smooth differential operator. In your nonsmooth case I don't know how to make sense of this.